# CSS: Clearing the Content after a 3-Column Div Layout

Tags: css, html

I cannot figure out how to clear the content below my 3 div columns--where each div column contains a span with some centered text and a textarea below the span.  The problem, or at least I think, is that the div tags are being floated, and I'm not properly clearing them.

What happens is Firefox floats my next element after the columns (in my case, a button) over the first column.  My local file renders perfectly in Internet Explorer (but I'm assuming that's because IE adds its own enclosing for clearing... can't find where I read that).  However, when I look at my jsFiddle code in IE, the textareas do not maintain their 100% height.  I'm assuming jsFiddle doesn't render HTML in IE's Quirks Mode (which is why it differs from my local file).

I've looked at the [Holy Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail) article, the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp) article, the [clear:after fix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) article, and several other articles ([div column layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3599475/1253609)), but couldn't come up with a working solution in both browsers.

Here is my [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/EcbWL/1/), and here is my code.  As you can see, my code has multiple methods, so I'm sorry for the mess.

**site.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top" class="clearfix">
            <div class="column">
                <span>blah1</span>
                <textarea class="text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <span>blah2</span>
                <textarea class="text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="column clearfix">
                <span>blah3</span>
                <textarea class="text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="clearing">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <span>blah blah blah</span>
            <input type="button" value="Button" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**site.css**

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#top {
  height: 40%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.column {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.clearing {
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#center {
  clear: both;
}
```

It's also good to note that I've tried adding in `overflow: hidden (and auto)`, which does solve the problem, but I want to see my entire textarea... not hide it/have it scroll.  Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take:

```
height: 40%;
```

Out of your #top deceleration in your CSS. That's causing the issue. If you want to make the textboxes larger simply use:

```
textarea{height:200px;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I'm also not looking to use fixed widths... I like my percentages.  :)

Comment: Well the reason it's overlapping is because you're seetting the textarea as 100% of it's container, so it's overlapping by the size of the span since the height of the inside is now the textarea(100%) + the span. you have to either give the textarea 80% and the span 20% or rethink how you want to lay them out.

Comment: Duh!  Right you are... that was a really dumb mistake.  So why would IE not care about that?

Comment: Pshh, cop out answer for IE, haha.  I'm thinking it's because the button right after the DIV has the hasLayout property... maybe?  This article explains a little about what I'm talking about http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html